# AR Quick Look doesn't work in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, swift-playground, ipad-playgrounds

I have a question regarding AR Quick Look, I have a simple view with an ARQLView showing a .usdz file of a Nike shoe. This code works perfectly fine on my iPad if I sideload the app using Xcode. The problem is, when I try to use the same code in Swift Playgrounds on the iPad, it gives the same view but with the "AR" mode grayed out, with the "Object" mode the only option. So I can pan and zoom the 3D model but I cannot see it in AR. Is this a limitation of Playgrounds, or is Playgrounds itself encountering a bug (which isn't uncommon in my experience).

I referred to this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-an-ios-ar-app-using-the-ar-quick-look-api-fe31aede5267) describing how to use AR Quick Look with SwiftUI with the following code in my Xcode project and Swift Playground:

Here's the ARQL View:

```
    import UIKit
    import QuickLook
    import ARKit
    
    class ARQLViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let assetName = "sneaker_airforce"
        let assetType = "usdz"
        let allowsContentScaling = true
        let canonicalWebPageURL = URL(string: "")
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            let previewController = QLPreviewController()
            previewController.dataSource = self
            present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: assetName, ofType: assetType) else {
                fatalError("Couldn't find the supported asset file.")
            }
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let previewItem = ARQuickLookPreviewItem(fileAt: url)
            previewItem.allowsContentScaling = allowsContentScaling // default = true
            previewItem.canonicalWebPageURL = canonicalWebPageURL   // default = nil
            return previewItem
        }
    }
```

Then that's wrapped up for use in SwiftUI:

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct ARQLView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        typealias UIViewControllerType = ARQLViewController
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            return Coordinator(self)
        }
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ARQLViewController {
            let viewController = ARQLViewController()
            return viewController
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ARQLViewController, context: Context) {
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSObject {
            var parent: ARQLView
            init(_ parent: ARQLView) {
                self.parent = parent
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I simply call the view when the user presses the button.

[Screenshot of app sideloaded with Xcode, then Playgrounds:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCIAs.jpg)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code. [This article](https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-swift-playgrounds-or-how-to-create-and-debug-ar-apps-on-ipad-pro-190a6d2e03bb) got it to work. What are you doing differently?

Comment: I apologize. Hopefully the edits I made are more helpful.